# Get index of DropDownList asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I want to get the value of the specifed index in a DropDownList

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DropDownList ddl = YourDropDownList;
//this
ddl.SelectedItem;
//or this
ddl.SelectedValue;
//or this
ddl.Items[ddl.SelectedIndex];
```

Any of those what you're after??